# defining haskell functions that have Maybe in signature

Tags: haskell

i'm unclear about how to write function signatures in haskell, especially using `Maybe`. consider:

```
f :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
f = \a -> a

main = print (f (Just 5))
```

this works but why can't the function signature just be this?

```
f :: Maybe -> Maybe
```

since `f` just takes a `Maybe` type and returns a `Maybe` type.

related: if i wanted to have the Maybe type be more specific and be a `Maybe Int`, why doesn't this work?

```
f :: Maybe Int a -> Maybe Int a
f = \a -> a

main = print (f (Just (Int 5)))
```

(i'm running all code using `runhaskell test.hs`)

Comment: You seem confused about what the `a` represents in the type signature. `Maybe` is not a type, it is a *type constructor*. You supply it with a type, and you get a new type, like `Maybe Int`, `Maybe Bool`, `Maybe [String]`, or `Maybe (Maybe Char)`. `Maybe` on its own is not a valid type, so `Maybe -> Maybe` is not a valid type, either. The `a` is a *type variable*, which stands in for some caller-supplied type, so `Maybe a -> Maybe a` means `a` can be any type, as long as it’s the same on both sides. The `a` has no relation to the `a` in your lambda, which is in another namespace entirely.

Comment: Since nobody seems to have mentioned it yet, `Int 5` is only valid if `Int` is a constructor (like `Just`, `Left`) but it isn't. If you want to say that `5` is of type `Int`, you could use a type annotation (`5 :: Int`) but in this case it's not needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like you are confused about type variables.  First of all, in

```
f :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
f = \a -> a
```

the `a`'s in the first line have nothing to do with the `a`'s in the second line, we could have written:

```
f :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
f = \x -> x
```

or even

```
f :: Maybe foo -> Maybe foo
f = \bar -> bar
```

The `a`'s are variables that stand for types.  So `f` here is declaring that `f` has a whole bunch of types at once:

```
f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
f :: Maybe String -> Maybe String
f :: Maybe (Maybe Bool) -> Maybe (Maybe Bool)
...
```

and so on.  It is not some "labeling" of the arguments as I suspect you think.  The fact that the two `a`'s are the same means that the argument type has to be the same result type.  If we had said `f :: Maybe a -> Maybe b` we would get this family:

```
f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Bool
f :: Maybe String -> Maybe String
f :: Maybe (Maybe Bool) -> Maybe Int
...
```

that is, the `a` and `b` can now stand for different types, but the argument and result still have to be `Maybe`.

The reason you can't say

```
f :: Maybe -> Maybe
```

is because `Maybe` is not a type -- it is a *type constructor*.  If you give it a type, it gives you back a type.  So `Maybe Int` and `Maybe String` are types, and in general `Maybe a` is a type as long as `a` is a type.

`Maybe Int a` (which is parsed `(Maybe Int) a`) has no meaning because `Maybe Int` is not a type constructor -- it does not accept any more arguments.

Suggested reading: [Types and Typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) from LYAH.

Answer (score 5):

`Maybe` is a type constructor, essentially a type-level function. It takes a type (such as `Int`) and returns a type (such as `Maybe Int`). The “types” of types are called *kinds*: the kind of a type that has values, like `Int`, is called `*`. The kind of a type constructor that takes one argument is `* -> *`. You can see this in GHCi with the `:kind`/`:k` command:

```
> :k Int
Int :: *

> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *

> :k Either
Either :: * -> * -> *
```

In a signature like `Maybe a -> Maybe a`, `a` is a *type variable* that gets replaced with a particular type when you call the function. (Implicitly, this means `forall a. Maybe a -> Maybe a`, which you can write yourself if you enable extensions such as `ExplicitForall` or `ScopedTypeVariables`.)

So if you call `f :: Maybe a -> Maybe a` on a `Maybe Int`, then `f` has the type `Maybe Int -> Maybe Int` at that call site, because `a` has been *instantiated* to `Int`.

The compiler rejects `Maybe Int a` because you’re supplying two parameters to `Maybe` when it only accepts one. (The `a` is not a name for the argument, but a parameter of the type.) Likewise, it rejects `Maybe -> Maybe` because you’ve given `Maybe` no arguments, so you’re trying to pass two types of kind `* -> *` to the function arrow constructor `(->)`, which takes arguments of kind `*`:

```
> :k (->)
(->) :: * -> * -> *
```

As an aside, it is possible to write something like `Maybe -> Maybe` and have it expand to `Maybe a -> Maybe a`, and this can be useful sometimes, but it’s almost certainly not what you’re intending to do right now.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

type (~>) f g = forall a. f a -> g a

f :: Maybe ~> Maybe
f x = x
```

Here, the type synonym `Maybe ~> Maybe` expands to `forall a. Maybe a -> Maybe a`, which can be abbreviated to `Maybe a -> Maybe a`, the signature you wrote before.